# My Gmail account is being used in another location

Tags: gmail, security

Actually, I do not know whether or not my Gmail account is compromised given the details.

I am on a desktop computer right now and logged in to my account.
I have got a Windows phone with Gmail synced *but* it is *another account*.
On the desktop computer, as soon as I log in, I can see a warning below on the right corner saying that *My account is being used in another location*. I click on *Details*  and it says that my account is used in another location but *strangely*, it has got the *same* IP address of my current location. I told you that I do not have it on my mobile phone, and it is always being used here (neither on my laptop!). So what is going on?

BTW, maybe it's because I have the Hangouts open as you can see on the left of the below image. Or maybe not, because such a thing has never happened before, but only for three weeks.
[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably is the Hangouts app. Other possible things might be if you've signed in to Chrome, Picasa, Google Music uploader, Google Photos backup, Google Drive. It could also be if you've logged in to Google with a different browser.

Since it's coming from the same IP, it's certainly something behind your router, so I don't think you have much to worry about. I'm no security expert, however.

One thing you can do is:

1. From Gmail, click the "details" link in the lower right, below any messages being displayed
2. On the activity page that is displayed, click the "Sign out all other web sessions" button
3. See what breaks

If it is Hangouts, or Google Drive sync, or whatever, you should get re-prompted to log in.

---

You can also have a look at your Google Account activity to get further clues.

Go [myaccount.google.com](https://myaccount.google.com) and look in the "Sign in & security" section. You can see any recent security alerts (like a changed password), what devices have connected, and what apps are connected to your account. You can also do a "Security checkup" to see if you're at risk and to tighten down your account. At the very least you may want to change your password.

Comment: The Hangouts App signs in automatically whilst Gmail is about to be opened and even though I am online on the Hangouts, at times it does not show that my account is being used in another location. So I really do not know whether or not it depends on the hangouts. Moreover, when I try to "sign out of all other web sessions", it does signs me out of all of them but nothing appears and I am NOT asked to log in again or the loading login bar appears [in blue]. Nothing whatever is my case.

Comment: Then you'll just need to decide for yourself it it's a real issue and use trial-and-error to see what is making the extra connection. For what it's worth, I regularly have 10 different connections showing on my activity from this IP address. I use most of the services I listed and my Android phone is on my wifi.

Comment: Got it, I decided that there is nothing to worry about.